# Loop through passed-in parameter in JS instead of template

Tags: ember.js

A parent component passes an array into a child component. I need to loop through that array in the component's JS file, rather than its template.

I know I can access the parameter using this.get('parameter'), but in JS it doesn't behave like an array.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't behave like an array? `this.get('parameter')` is the way to access it, like you mention.

Comment: It's a super complex class with stuff like _prevArrangedContent, isLoaded, etc. It's probably because I'm using Ember Data.

Comment: Is it a relationship? It might be a `PromiseArray`. You should still be able to use it like a regular array, since calls get proxied to the resolved content, but without more details from your application it's very tricky to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work as you expect! [Checkout this ember-twiddle.](https://ember-twiddle.com/fb6dbf857f6c1a2a085e?openFiles=application.template.hbs%2Cchild-component.component.js)

If you have an Array outside the component you will get an array inside the component!

So your problem is on a completely other place.

Ember itself will always give you an [Ember.Enumerable](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html). You can use `.forEach(x => { ...doStuff.. })` on them.

Ember-data gives you a `PromiseArray` for store operations and relationships.

You can use `.forEach` safely on the `PromiseArray` if you are in a ComputedProperty (CP) which is depending on that `PromiseArray`, because the CP will fire again when the Promise resolves. Outside of an CP, for example in an hook or an action you **should** resolve the Promise with `.then(arr => arr.forEach(item => doSomething(item)))`!

So this is safe:

```
all: Ember.computed('myArr', {
  get() {
    let str = '';
    this.get('myArr').forEach(item => str+=item.get('name'));
    return str;
  }
})
```

And this is safe:

```
actions: {
  alertIt() {
    this.get('myArr').then(arr => {
      let str = '';
      arr.forEach(item => str+=item.get('name'));
      alert(str);
    });
  }
}
```

But this is **wrong**:

```
actions: {
  alertIt() {
    let str = '';
    this.get('myArr').forEach(item => str+=item.get('name'));
    alert(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much